# MySQL query - Anniversary of Date Field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am setting up a mysql database with 2 fields one is a name (text string) and one with a date. `yyyy-mm-dd.`

I need to query the table to show only the names that match the dd-mm. So on the anniversary of that date every year those names get printed.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM FRSLNamelist WHERE $dateofdeath"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo $line['fullname'];
echo "<br>";
```

I can't find anywhere how to do this.
I know that you can explode the date field separated so you only have to match the month and day.

I need the function to do:

If `[datefield] = [current.day.month]` then `print [name]`.

anybody have  quick fix.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the stored date is in format `yyyy-mm-dd` as you mentioned, and you have to ignore the `yyyy` part then one way would be:

```
$dateOfdeath=date("m-d");
$query = "SELECT * FROM FRSLNamelist WHERE  dateField LIKE '%-$dateofdeath'";
```

**Another, even better, way would be:**

```
$d=date("d");
$m=date("m");
$query = "SELECT * FROM FRSLNamelist WHERE MONTH(dateField)=$m AND DAY(dateField)=$d";
```

**Edit:**

> with the dateFieldName, could i use curdate?

Yes

```
SELECT * FROM FRSLNamelist 
WHERE MONTH(dateField)=MONTH(CURDATE())
AND DAY(dateField)=DAY(CURDATE())
```

Comment: with the dateFieldName, could i use curdate?

Comment: Perfect Mate, Cheers.